# How to call function when document on change?

Tags: javascript

I have a function:

```
function emailCheck() {
    //some function codes
}
```

I want to call him like this:

```
$(document).on('keyup', 'input', emailCheck())
```

But it's not calling the function.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure you want to fire the email check every time the user presses a button? Seems like something you'd only do when they're typing in the email field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I did it suddenly...

The right syntax:

```
$(document).on('keyup', 'input', emailCheck)
```

Answer (score 0):

The third argument to `on` takes a reference to a callback function to be executed as the event handler. When you write `emailCheck()` there, you're actually invoking the function right away. Instead, just do `$(document).on('keyup', 'input', emailCheck)`